# Ignore language in MongoDB text index

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I am trying to create a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#index-feature-text) in my MongoDB. The field I am trying to index is in the Czech language (cs), which is not supported (as it's not listed [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/text-search-languages/#text-search-languages)).

I would still like to index it, even if the stop words and other language specific features won't work. But I'm getting an error. Here is what I tried:

```
db.myCollection.createIndex( {"translate.cs.content" : "text"} )
```

I also tried to change default language:

```
db.myCollection.createIndex( {"translate.cs.content" : "text"}, {"default_language" : "none"} )
db.myCollection.createIndex( {"translate.cs.content" : "text"}, {"default_language" : "en"} )
```

But all of these approaches give me this error:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Index build failed: <...>: Collection myDatabase.myCollection( <...> ) :: caused 
by :: language override unsupported: cs",
    "code" : 17262,
    "codeName" : "Location17262"
}
```

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/text-search-languages/#text-search-languages) says:

> If you specify a language value of "none", then the text search uses simple tokenization with no list of stop words and no stemming.

That is what I need, I just need to be able to search exact words within long strings. Is there any way how to make Mongo ignore the language?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to specify `cs` language somewhere, locate where that is happening and get rid of that.

Comment: Any idea where that could be? I just did a pure installation and inserted the data. Is there any specific config file or something that I should check?

Comment: You can turn on query logging and grep the queries sent for cs.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by adding a `language_override` like this.

```
db.myCollection.createIndex( {"translate.cs.content": "text"}, 
    {default_language: "none", language_override: "none"} )
```

The reason was that I had another field called `language` somewhere else in my data.

Comment: I also had the language field specified on my docs and was getting the same issue. Your solution works for me!

Comment: You answer saved my day. I just renamed the field I already created with the name 'language' to make it work! Thanks.